# create a Select Box form From Database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 select box in this form, the first select box is done and works.

...But when I add the second select box, the error appears like the picture..

here's the code

This is the first select box - it works:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' =>route('units.store'), 'method' => 'post' ))}}

  <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('brand_id')) has-error @endif">
    <label>Brand Manufacture</label>
    {{Form::select('brand_id', $brand, null, ['class' => 'form-control w450']) }}
    @if ($errors->has('brand_id')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('brand_id') }}</p> @endif
  </div>
```

And this is the select that is not right:

```
 <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('model_id')) has-error @endif">
    <label>Model Type</label>
    {{Form::select('model_id',$model, null, ['class' => 'form-control w450']) }}
    @if ($errors->has('model_id')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('model_id') }}</p> @endif
  </div>
```

And this is the whole code.

```
  {{ Form::open(array('url' =>route('units.store'), 'method' => 'post' ))}}

  <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('brand_id')) has-error @endif">
    <label>Brand Manufacture</label>
    {{Form::select('brand_id', $brand, null, ['class' => 'form-control w450']) }}
    @if ($errors->has('brand_id')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('brand_id') }}</p> @endif
  </div>


  <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('model_id')) has-error @endif">
    <label>Model Type</label>
    {{Form::select('model_id',$model, null, ['class' => 'form-control w450']) }}
    @if ($errors->has('model_id')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('model_id') }}</p> @endif
  </div>

  <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('kva')) has-error @endif">
    <label>kva</label>
    <input name="kva" type="text" class="form-control w450"  value="{{ Input::old('kva') }}">
    @if ($errors->has('kva')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('kva') }}</p> @endif
  </div>

  <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('type')) has-error @endif">
    <label>Type</label>
    <select name="type" id="" class="form-control w450">
      <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
      <option value="CLOSE">CLOSE</option>
    </select>
    @if ($errors->has('type')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('type') }}</p> @endif
  </div>

  <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('sn')) has-error @endif">
    <label>Serial Number</label>
    <input name="sn" type="text" class="form-control w450"  value="{{ Input::old('sn') }}">
    @if ($errors->has('sn')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('sn') }}</p> @endif
  </div>

   <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('wbs_unit')) has-error @endif">
    <label>WBS unit</label>
    <input name="wbs_unit" type="text" class="form-control w450"  value="{{ Input::old('wbs_unit') }}">
    @if ($errors->has('wbs_unit')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('wbs_unit') }}</p> @endif
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">create</button>
  </div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

I can't post any image :(

so help me..please

Comment: this the link  http://file.tpops.net/?d=dXBsb2Fkcy9NSUZUQUgvZXJycnIuanBn&t=1420749231&h=2f4f95fc85a221fd7c60ea40b491ffed  use this user and password to akses  the link  for user is tpops  and password is tpops2015

Comment: Since you can't post any image, what is the error? Can you properly var_dump `$model`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're pulling data from the database in the correct format for the select box. It should be an associative array with the key being the database ID and the value being the string you want to show in the dropdown. Here's an example.

```
$brands = Brand::lists('name', 'id');
// Example: ['1' => 'Adidas', '2' => 'Nike', '3' => 'New Balance;];

{{ Form::select('brand_id', $brands) }}
```

Also, you can simplify your error class using a ternary statement, something like this.

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('brand_id') ? 'has-error' : null }}">
```